# Why does RUnit change my random numbers?

Tags: r, random, runit

In a unit test I start a helper function (generating test data) with:

```
set.seed(1)
```

I was developing the unit test interactively like this:

```
source('tests/runit.functions.R');test.something()
```

But then when I went to run the tests from my `run_tests.R` they failed. I narrowed it down to different random numbers, despite the `set.seed(1)` command! I added this line, just after set.seed(1):

```
print(sessionInfo());print("RANDOM SEED:");print(.Random.seed)
```

The really interesting part is the random seed is entirely different. In the batch script it is just three numbers:

```
501 1280795612 -169270483
```

Whereas in my interactive R session it is a 626-element monster:

```
[1]         403         624  -169270483  -442010614 ...
 ...
[617]   197184543    -2095148  ... -689249108
```

The first number, the 501 vs. 403, is the type of random number generator, apparently, but I couldn't track down the master list for what the numbers mean.

I think the core of my question is what is the best way to make sure my unit tests have reliable random number generation? A secondary question is troubleshooting advice: how do I track down which random number generator is being used (and more importantly) which code/package/setting decided to use that?

The `sessionInfo` is not looking very helpful, but it is showing some small differences. E.g. the inclusion of the TTR package is due to other unit tests being run. Here is `sessionInfo` output from the batch script, where the first line is `#!/usr/bin/Rscript --slave`:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C              LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C            LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     

other attached packages:
[1] TTR_0.21-1   xts_0.8-6    zoo_1.7-7    RUnit_0.4.26

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1    lattice_0.20-6
```

And here is the output from my interactive R session, which is started from the commandline with `R --no-save`:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C              LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C            LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.8-6    zoo_1.7-7    RUnit_0.4.26

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1    lattice_0.20-6 tools_2.15.1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you are using the `RUnit` package for your unit tests. In this case, you need to be aware that `RUnit` uses a different default for the *kind* of random number generator (`RNGkind`).

From the [RUnit manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/RUnit.pdf), and the help for `?defineTestSuite`:

```
defineTestSuite(name, dirs, testFileRegexp = "^runit.+\\.[rR]$",
  testFuncRegexp = "^test.+",  
  rngKind = "Marsaglia-Multicarry",
  rngNormalKind = "Kinderman-Ramage")
```

Notice that the default `rngKind` in `RUnit` is **"Marsaglia-Multicarry"**.

However, in base R, the default `RNGkind` is **"Mersenne-Twister"**. From `?RNGkind`:

> *The currently available RNG kinds are given below. kind is partially
>   matched to this list. The default is "Mersenne-Twister".*

---

So, to match your interactive results with the results of `RUnit`, you need to set a different `RNGkind`, either in your interactive session or in your initial call to `defineTestSuite`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. From the `defineTestSuite` help it says: "_this default has been chosen due to historical reasons and differs from the current R default_". So I've changed my run_tests.R to use: `rngKind = "Mersenne-Twister",rngNormalKind = "Inversion"` and my tests now pass!